# How can I hide Instance object?

Tags: modifiers, instances, curve-modifier

I'm trying to create curved conveyor with array and curve. To avoid bending deformation I'm using Faces Instancing. How can I hide the Instance?

[image]

There is Show Instancer checkboxes, but it doesn't hide the cube (only hides planes uder the instances)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be visible in render, but in preview you can press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide.

Comment: Hah, it works! Thanx.